# Is it possible to get the property of the folder on the server through FTP

Tags: file, ftp, download

I want to download image from a remote server. The protocol is FTP. Is it possible to get the property of the folder on the server, for example the name and last modified date,  in order to decide whether I should down load the image in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using?

It's definitely possible, as the information is available. [Here's a solution in php.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462269/get-modified-date-via-ftp-using-php-curl)